# Активность пользователя и блокировка

Tags: jquery

Пользователь оставляет открытой страницу браузера (может не появляться сутки), но так как страница открыта, то все фоновые Ajax-запросы выполняются (обновление элементов страницы). Я считаю это лишней тратой ресурсов сервера в отсутствие пользователя. Вопросы:

**1.** Как вычислить, что в течение 10 минут пользователь не производит на странице никаких действий?

**2.** Как полностью заблокировать выполнение JS до появления активности на странице?

**3.** Как узнать, что на странице появилась активность?

Сайт адаптивный. Поэтому используется на всех устройствах. Если к примеру, на компьютере можно поймать движение мыши и посчитать это активностью, то на мобильных mouse не работает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предлагаю определять активен пользователь или нет как-то так:

```js
let timeout = 3000;
let lastActiveTimestamp = 0;
let userIsActive = false;

window.addEventListener('mousemove', active);
window.addEventListener('keypress', active);
window.addEventListener('click', active);

setInterval(checkUserIsActive, 1000)
active();

function checkUserIsActive() {
  if (userIsActive && new Date().getTime() - lastActiveTimestamp > timeout){
    console.log('user is not active');
    document.querySelector('div').textContent = 'user is inactive';
    userIsActive = false;
  }
}

function active() {
  lastActiveTimestamp = new Date().getTime();
  if (!userIsActive) {
    userIsActive = true;
    console.log('user is active');
    document.querySelector('div').textContent = 'user is active';
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="color:red"></div>
<br><br><br>
<span>Нажмие на любую клавишу или двигайте мышь<span>
```

PS: тут стоят проверки на `mousemove`, `click` и `keypress`

PPS: жуквери тут и не пахнет ибо **а зачем?**