# Активность пользователя JS, JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Возможно ли на JS определить активность пользователя?

**Подробнее:** Пользователь заходит на страницу и выполняем функцию `test()` каждые 30 секунд. Теперь главное: Если через 5 минут пользователь не был активен на странице, то мы прекращаем её выполнение до появления активности на странице.

Если это возможно, то подскажите какие методы `JS` или `JQuery` можно для этого использовать?

Comment: Трекать активность мышки/клавиатуры/касаний, например )

Comment: такой вопрос неоднократно задавался

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/963757/188366

Comment: @StrangerintheQ там только частица ответа. Там функция `test()` будет выполняться при каждой активности. Например если в `test()` Ajax запрос, то одним взмахом мышки можно отправить тысячи запросов к серверу

Comment: @OlimpES читайте внимательнее, там меняется статус элемента только тогда когда происходит изменение состояния активности

Comment: @OlimpES изменил ответ там, чтобы было понятно по выводу в консоль, когда происходит событие и когда надо отправлять `ajax`

Comment: @StrangerintheQ всё нормально, кроме одного. Если active, т.е постоянно махать курсором, то test() каждые 30 секунд при активности не вызывается. Она вызывается только: `Active: test()   NoActive: ---  Active: test()`. Не подскажите как вызывать test() каждые 30 секунд если постоянно Active?

Comment: Я думаю для этого можно завести отдельный интервал и просто раз в 30 секунд отправлять если переменная userIsActive=== true