# Как проверять активность пользователя на странице React?

Tags: reactjs

Есть такая задачка:

> Когда пользователь находиться на странице и ничего не делает (просто
> сидит и читает статью или просто отошёл от экрана) запускается таймер
> и если за это время пользователь не делал никаких действий - его нужно
> выкинуть из профиля.
> На беке у меня есть свойство, которое true до тех пор, пока
> пользователь делает запросы и у его есть 30 минут чтобы сделать ещё
> один запрос, чтобы обнулить таймер и если он его не сделает - false.

Думал сделать это при помощи Page Visibility API, но в документации не нашёл такого значения, которое будет отвечать за то, что страница активная, а действий никаких нет.
Видел ещё на данном форуме еще [одну реализацию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/963751/%D0%90%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0) через прослушивание событий.

Сам думал сделать на фронте через сеттаймаут (каждую минуту отправлять
запрос и проверять какое значение имеет это поле), но если будет много пользователей - боюсь нагрузка будет очень большая, т.к будет очень много запросов.

Какие есть ещё способы реализации данной задачи и какая будет самая оптимальная в плане быстродействия? Ибо по мере роста сайта - боюсь второй вариант сильно повлияет на быстродействие.